# Agrupar dados - Collection Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, collection

Preciso agrupar os dados de uma função SQL em Indicadores e Data, porém em minha tentativa de agrupar, estou apenas conseguindo por data(Coluna), por este motivo os dados se repetem.

Model:

```
public static function makeCluster($date, $flag_negocio)
{
    /** @var static $instance */
    $instance = new static;

    $table = sprintf('QLIKVIEW.dbo.FN_QLIKVIEW_PAGAMENTOS_DASHBOARD_CLUSTER_CNC(\'%s\',\'%s\')',
        $date,
        $flag_negocio
    );

    return $instance->setTable($table);
}
```

Controller:

```
$clusters = Pagamentos::makeCluster($data, $flag_negocio)
    ->selectRaw('DATA_PAGAMENTO, RAZAO_CLI, SUM(VALOR_PAGAMENTO) AS VALOR_PAGAMENTO')
    ->groupBy('RAZAO_CLI', 'DATA_PAGAMENTO')
    ->orderBy('RAZAO_CLI')
    ->get();
```

View:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title text-center">Pagamento Cluster - Ronaldo</h4>
</div>

@if($clusters->isNotEmpty())
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover report report-sm">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="bg-info text-center">Indicador</th>
                @foreach($clusters as $key => $cluster)
                    <th class="bg-info text-center">{{ $cluster->first()->DATA_PAGAMENTO}}</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($clusters as $cluster)
                <tr>
                    <th class="bg-info">{{ $cluster->RAZAO_CLI  }}</th>
                    @foreach($clusters as $cluster)
                        <td>{{ $cluster->first()->VALOR_PAGAMENTO ?? '&mdash;' }}</td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
@else
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="text-center text-danger">Não há dados para essa seleção.</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

Print do visual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Falha no Collection Laravel 5.6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/337873/falha-no-collection-laravel-5-6)

Comment: Do jeito que você demostra os dados fica complicado entender o que realmente precisa, e pior essa é uma duplicata dessa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/337873/falha-no-collection-laravel-5-6 não é válido ... Tente clarear o máximo, por exemplo quais os campos dessa tabela?, porque está agrupado como no desenho, qual tabela você faz essa SQL?